# set the value of struct property in different Viewcontrollers in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I have used struct to set constant.I have maxTextLength in integer form I have to set different values for different controller like one for 300 and another 1000.Here is my code

```
    struct Validations {
    static let maxAudioRecSec:Int = 150
    static var maxTextLength = 300 // Default value
    }
    SecondVC :ViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad () {
          Validations.maxTextLength = 1000
    } 
   }
```

So value changed inside SecondVC is retain inside that controller only that is 1000.If I access this value inside another controller should be default 300.

Comment: If you want different values you need different instances of the struct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must use like below, don't use static variable for `maxTextLength`.

```
struct Validations {
    static let maxAudioRecSec:Int = 150
    var maxTextLength = 300 // Default value
 }
```

Now in any `ViewController` you must use like below.

```
class SecondVC :ViewController {
var validations = Validations() // create Validations struct object
    override func viewDidLoad () {
          validations.maxTextLength = 1000 // use like this
    } 
   }
```

Any doubt plz comment.

Comment: Thanks for reply .But after using this code inside viewController I'm getting this error "Static member 'maxTextLength' cannot be used on instance of type 'Validations'"

Comment: Ya you need to remove static keyword from maxTextLength variable , check my ans. properly.

Comment: Bhavin & Vivek thanks a lot.It works. if my question is valid then you can upvote it.